# Dropdown menu - I have to double click to open after changing the options

Tags: html, jquery, tailwind-css

I have dropdown menu (pagination menu) in my blade with tailwind.
When I open page by first time, menu had opened after one click, but when I want to change option by second time, I have to click twice to open it.

My code:

**index.blade.php**

```
<a class="w-20 items-actual-count text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">10 </a>
<!-- Dropdown menu -->
<div id="dropdown" class="items-count z-10 hidden bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" x-placement="bottom-end" style="will-change: transform; position: absolute; transform: translate3d(120px, 48px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px;">
  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">10</a>
  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">20</a>
  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">50</a>
  <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">100</a>
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
$(function() {
    $('div.items-count a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('a.items-actual-count').text($(this).text());
        getItems($(this).text());
    });
});
```

When I inspect page I have:

1. At the beginning - `data-popper-placement="bottom"`

```
<div id="dropdown" class="items-count z-10 hidden bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" x-placement="bottom-end" style="will-change: transform; position: absolute; transform: translate3d(976.5px, 830px, 0px); inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px;" data-popper-placement="bottom">
```

2. After change - `data-popper-placement="top"`

```
<div id="dropdown" class="items-count z-10 bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700 hidden" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" x-placement="bottom-end" style="will-change: transform; position: absolute; inset: auto auto 0px 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(245.5px, -66px, 0px);" data-popper-placement="top">
```

3. After first click after change - `data-popper-placement="bottom"`

```
<div id="dropdown" class="items-count z-10 hidden bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" x-placement="bottom-end" style="will-change: transform; position: absolute; transform: translate3d(976.5px, 830px, 0px); inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px;" data-popper-placement="bottom">
```

Comment: Are oyu sure this is a problem related to PHP or Blade? If yes, please share more details about that connection. Anyways, share what you've tried to resolve the problem